# Usb flash - определение интерфейса.

Tags: usb, железо, hdd

Как программно определить, по какому интерфейсу usb 2  или 3 подключен диск или флешка?

или вариант два 
Как определить все USB порты в системе  и порт куда именно сделано включение. Тогда я буду знать как подключена флешка или диск?

Comment: а операционную систему указать?

Answer (score 1):

### Решение на C++ для Windows

Определить версию USB можно с помощью [Setup API](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/setupapi) и запросов `DeviceIoControl`. Нас интересуют запросы:

[IOCTL_USB_GET_NODE_CONNECTION_INFORMATION_EX](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff537321(v=vs.85).aspx) - возвращает сведения о фактически используемой в данный момент версии USB

[IOCTL_USB_GET_NODE_CONNECTION_INFORMATION_EX_V2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh450861(v=vs.85).aspx) - возвращает сведения о поддерживаемых версиях USB

Алгоритм следующий:

1. Функцией `SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces` найти все интерфейсы USB-концентраторов.
2. Для каждого концентратора функцией `SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail` получить путь к устройству - строку, которую можно скармливать функции `CreateFile` вместо пути к файлу, для отправки IOCTL.
3. Через `IOCTL_USB_GET_HUB_INFORMATION_EX` получить число портов на концентраторе.
4. Для каждого порта отправкой `IOCTL_USB_GET_NODE_CONNECTION_INFORMATION_EX` и/или `IOCTL_USB_GET_NODE_CONNECTION_INFORMATION_EX_V2` получить сведения о порте.
5. Пользуясь полями полученной структуры `USB_DEVICE_DESCRIPTOR`, можно определить *VID* и *PID*, и далее с помощью них другие необходимые параметры для идентификации устройства (*Friendly Name, Service* и т.п.)

---

Пример кода на c++ для вывода названия, идентификатора, версий USB-протокола и текущей скорости для всех запоминающих USB-устройств, основан на [коде из ответа MrMoDoJoJr на stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36728329/8674428):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>    
#include <Windows.h>
#include <Setupapi.h>
#include <winusb.h>

#undef LowSpeed
#include <Usbioctl.h>

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <Devpkey.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <memory>
#include <strsafe.h>

#pragma comment(lib,"Setupapi.lib")


void ErrorMes(LPTSTR lpszFunction) 
{ 
    // Retrieve the system error message for the last-error code

    LPVOID lpMsgBuf;
    LPVOID lpDisplayBuf;
    DWORD dw = GetLastError(); 

    FormatMessage(
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | 
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM |
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
        NULL,
        dw,
        MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT),
        (LPTSTR) &lpMsgBuf,
        0, NULL );

    // Display the error message 

    lpDisplayBuf = (LPVOID)LocalAlloc(LMEM_ZEROINIT, 
        (lstrlen((LPCTSTR)lpMsgBuf) + lstrlen((LPCTSTR)lpszFunction) + 40) * sizeof(TCHAR)); 
    wprintf(L"%s failed with error %d: %s", 
        lpszFunction, dw, lpMsgBuf);     

    LocalFree(lpMsgBuf);
    LocalFree(lpDisplayBuf);

}

typedef struct {
    wchar_t name[1024];//friendly name
    wchar_t id[1024];//instance id

} USB_DEVICE_PARAMS;

/*Получение имени устройства с указанным InstanceID*/
BOOL GetDevice(wchar_t* id,wchar_t* output)
{
    unsigned index;
    HDEVINFO hDevInfo;
    SP_DEVINFO_DATA DeviceInfoData;
    TCHAR id_upper[1024]=L"";
    TCHAR buf[1024]=L"";
    TCHAR match[1024];
    DEVPROPTYPE dpt=0;


        for(int i=0;i<wcslen(id);i++){
            id_upper[i]=toupper(id[i]);//преобразование в заглавные буквы
        }



    // List all connected devices
    hDevInfo = SetupDiGetClassDevs(NULL, NULL, NULL, DIGCF_PRESENT | DIGCF_ALLCLASSES);
    for (index = 0; ; index++) {
        DeviceInfoData.cbSize = sizeof(DeviceInfoData);
        if (!SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo(hDevInfo, index, &DeviceInfoData)) {
            return FALSE;     // no match
        }

        BOOL res=SetupDiGetDeviceProperty(hDevInfo,&DeviceInfoData,
                        &DEVPKEY_Device_InstanceId,&dpt,(PBYTE)buf,1000,NULL,0);
            if(res==FALSE)continue;


        if(wcscmp(buf,id_upper)==0){
            //устройство найдено
            res=SetupDiGetDeviceProperty(hDevInfo,&DeviceInfoData,
                        &DEVPKEY_Device_FriendlyName,&dpt,(PBYTE)buf,1000,NULL,0);

            wcscpy(output,buf);//возврат имени

            return TRUE;
        }


    }
    return FALSE;//устройство не найдено

}

/*Получение USB Mass Storage Device по указанным VID и PID*/
BOOL GetMassStorageDevice(int vid,int pid,USB_DEVICE_PARAMS* output)
{
    unsigned index;
    HDEVINFO hDevInfo;
    SP_DEVINFO_DATA DeviceInfoData;
    TCHAR HardwareID[1024];
    TCHAR buf[1024];

    TCHAR match[1024];
    DEVPROPTYPE dpt=0;
    BOOL res;

    //формируем строку для поиска
    StringCchPrintf(match,1024,L"VID_%04X&PID_%04X",vid,pid);


    // List all connected USB devices
    hDevInfo = SetupDiGetClassDevs(NULL, TEXT("USB"), NULL, DIGCF_PRESENT | DIGCF_ALLCLASSES);
    for (index = 0; ; index++) {
        DeviceInfoData.cbSize = sizeof(DeviceInfoData);
        if (!SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo(hDevInfo, index, &DeviceInfoData)) {
            return FALSE;     // no match
        }

        res=SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty(hDevInfo, &DeviceInfoData, SPDRP_HARDWAREID, NULL, 
            (BYTE*)HardwareID, sizeof(HardwareID),  NULL);
        if(res==FALSE)continue;

        if (_tcsstr(HardwareID, match)) {//найдено устройство, проверяем его тип
            res=SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty(hDevInfo, &DeviceInfoData, SPDRP_SERVICE, NULL, 
            (BYTE*)buf, sizeof(buf),    NULL);
            if(res==FALSE)continue;

             if(wcscmp(buf,L"USBSTOR")==0){//устройство является Mass Storage
                res=SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty(hDevInfo, &DeviceInfoData, SPDRP_DEVICEDESC, NULL, 
                (BYTE*)buf, sizeof(buf),    NULL);
                if(res==FALSE)continue;

                //получаем дочернее устройство
                res=SetupDiGetDeviceProperty(hDevInfo,&DeviceInfoData,
                        &DEVPKEY_Device_Children,&dpt,(PBYTE)buf,1000,NULL,0);
                if(res==FALSE)continue;//нет дочерних устройств

                wcscpy(output->id,buf);//возврат ID

                GetDevice(buf,output->name);//возврат имени устройства

                return TRUE;     // найдено 
             }
        }
    }
    return FALSE;//не найдено

}



int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"Russian");

    GUID guid;
    /*USB HUB Interface class GUID*/
    HRESULT hr = CLSIDFromString(L"{F18A0E88-C30C-11D0-8815-00A0C906BED8}", (LPCLSID)&guid);

    HDEVINFO deviceInfoHandle = SetupDiGetClassDevs(&guid, 0, 0, DIGCF_PRESENT | DIGCF_DEVICEINTERFACE);

    if (deviceInfoHandle != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        int deviceIndex = 0;
        while (true)
        {
            SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA deviceInterface = { 0 };
            deviceInterface.cbSize = sizeof(SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA);

            //получение всех USB-концентраторов
            if (SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces(deviceInfoHandle, 0, &guid, deviceIndex, &deviceInterface))
            {
                DWORD cbRequired = 0;

                SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail(deviceInfoHandle, &deviceInterface, 0, 0, &cbRequired, 0);
                if (ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER == GetLastError())
                {
                    PSP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA deviceInterfaceDetail = 
                        (PSP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA)(new char[cbRequired]);
                    memset(deviceInterfaceDetail, 0, cbRequired);
                    deviceInterfaceDetail->cbSize = sizeof(SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA);

                    if (!SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail(deviceInfoHandle, &deviceInterface, 
                        deviceInterfaceDetail, cbRequired, &cbRequired, 0))
                    {
                        deviceIndex++;
                        continue;
                    }

                    // Initialize the structure before using it.
                    memset(deviceInterfaceDetail, 0, cbRequired);
                    deviceInterfaceDetail->cbSize = sizeof(SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA);

                    // Call the API a second time to retrieve the actual
                    // device path string.
                    BOOL status = SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail(
                        deviceInfoHandle,  // Handle to device information set
                        &deviceInterface,     // Pointer to current node in devinfo set
                        deviceInterfaceDetail,   // Pointer to buffer to receive device path
                        cbRequired,   // Length of user-allocated buffer
                        &cbRequired,  // Pointer to arg to receive required buffer length
                        NULL);        // Not interested in additional data

                    BOOL res;                   

                    /*Открываем устройство для отправки IOCTL*/
                    HANDLE handle = CreateFile(deviceInterfaceDetail->DevicePath, GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_WRITE, 
                        0, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0);

                    if(handle!=INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {

                        //получаем число портов на концентраторе
                        DWORD bytes_read=0;
                        USB_HUB_INFORMATION_EX hubinfo;
                        hubinfo.HighestPortNumber=0;

                        res=DeviceIoControl(handle,IOCTL_USB_GET_HUB_INFORMATION_EX  ,
                            &hubinfo,sizeof(hubinfo),&hubinfo,sizeof(hubinfo),&bytes_read,0);
                        if(res==FALSE)ErrorMes(L"DeviceIoControl");                     

                        USB_NODE_CONNECTION_INFORMATION_EX coninfo={0};//get conn info
                        USB_NODE_CONNECTION_INFORMATION_EX_V2 con2={0};

                        for(int j=1;j<=(int)hubinfo.HighestPortNumber;j++){

                            coninfo.ConnectionIndex=j;

                            //получаем инфу о порте
                            res=DeviceIoControl(handle,IOCTL_USB_GET_NODE_CONNECTION_INFORMATION_EX ,
                            &coninfo,sizeof(coninfo),&coninfo,sizeof(coninfo),&bytes_read,0);

                            if(res==FALSE){ErrorMes(L"DeviceIoControl");continue;}

                            if(coninfo.ConnectionStatus==0)continue;

                            USB_DEVICE_PARAMS usbdev={0};

                            //если на порте запоминающее устройство, вывести его данные

                            if(GetMassStorageDevice(coninfo.DeviceDescriptor.idVendor,
                                    coninfo.DeviceDescriptor.idProduct,&usbdev)!=FALSE)
                            {
                                printf("\n- Hub %2d, Port %2d: USB v%x device\n",deviceIndex,
                                    j,(int)coninfo.DeviceDescriptor.bcdUSB);
                                printf("VID_%04X PID_%04X\n",(int)coninfo.DeviceDescriptor.idVendor
                                    ,(int)coninfo.DeviceDescriptor.idProduct);
                                wprintf(L"Device ID: %s\n",usbdev.id);
                                wprintf(L"Device name: %s\n",usbdev.name);
                                printf("Speed: %d",(int)coninfo.Speed);

                                switch((int)coninfo.Speed){
                                    case UsbLowSpeed:printf(" (low)\n");break;
                                    case UsbFullSpeed:printf(" (full)\n");break;
                                    case UsbHighSpeed:printf(" (high)\n");break;
                                    case UsbSuperSpeed:printf(" (super)\n");break;
                                    default:printf("\n");break;
                                }

                                //получение поддерживаемых протоколов
                                con2.ConnectionIndex=j;
                                con2.Length=sizeof(USB_NODE_CONNECTION_INFORMATION_EX_V2 );
                                con2.SupportedUsbProtocols.Usb300=1;

                                res=DeviceIoControl(handle, IOCTL_USB_GET_NODE_CONNECTION_INFORMATION_EX_V2 ,
                                &con2,sizeof(con2),&con2,sizeof(con2),&bytes_read,0);
                                if(res==FALSE){ErrorMes(L"DeviceIoControl");continue;}

                                printf("Supported protocols: ");
                                if(con2.SupportedUsbProtocols.Usb110)printf("USB 1.1; ");
                                if(con2.SupportedUsbProtocols.Usb200)printf("USB 2.0; ");
                                if(con2.SupportedUsbProtocols.Usb300)printf("USB 3.0; ");                               
                                printf("\n");
                            }


                        }//end for

                        CloseHandle(handle);
                    }else{
                        ErrorMes(L"CreateFile");//failed to open device
                    }//endif


                    delete[] deviceInterfaceDetail;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }

            ++deviceIndex;
        }

        SetupDiDestroyDeviceInfoList(deviceInfoHandle);
    }

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Так выглядит результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Примечание.** Информация выше относится к Windows 8-10. В более ранних ОС запросы на получение версии не поддерживаются, но можно получить признак поддержки High Speed:

```
DWORD bytes_read=0;
USB_HUB_CAPABILITIES_EX hubinfo={0};

res=DeviceIoControl(handle, IOCTL_USB_GET_HUB_CAPABILITIES  ,
                            &hubinfo,sizeof(hubinfo),&hubinfo,sizeof(hubinfo),&bytes_read,0);
if(res==FALSE)ErrorMes(L"DeviceIoControl");                     

printf("Supports High speed: %d\n",hubinfo.CapabilityFlags.HubIsHighSpeedCapable);
```

Answer (score 0):

Через обычный флеш или AIR вообще никак не определить.

Можно только узнать removable диск или нет, через класс [StorageVolume](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/StorageVolume.html)

Разве что писать своё ANE расширение для AIR приложения.

Теоретически возможно как то по скорости записи/чтения данных, но слабо представляю способ уйти от скорости собственно самого накопителя.

Comment: я хочу сделать тестирование дисков или флешек и мне нужно понимать через какой интерфейс  оно было подключено.
Соответенно, будет написан софт для windows и macos..

Comment: air не хочу использовать. Бдует обычный софт. Обычный exe )

Comment: если ехе, то можно такой способ, запускаем из флеша утилиту USBDeview
c параметрами - "usbdeview /stext 1.txt"
затем читаем "1.txt" и парсим его на предмет инфы юсб девайсов, в наличии и версия юсб устройства
"USB Version       : 1.10"